# ubuntu 16.04 screen turns to gray scale

Tags: ubuntu, grayscale

Using ubuntu 16.04, x86_64, nvidia gtx-960 graphics card, nvidia driver 357.67.  Using SDL2 for checker board.

In my checker program, when the computer is determining its next move and takes longer than about 7 seconds (which is most of the time), the checker board and checkers turn to gray scale. Once the move calculations are finished, the screen returns to the color mode.

In the SDL2 event loop I am setting the SDL_USEREVENT every 125 ms.

I am not using a battery or a laptop.  There is no option to dim the screen on 16.04.  I tried xscreensaver and turned the screensaver off.  I tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 180
```

but still got the dimming.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu turns apps to grayscale if they freeze, and then turns them back when they unfreeze. You're making your program do long, blocking calculations on the user-interface thread, which makes the program freeze until they're done. You should move such long-running activity to a different thread.